# Date Offset depending on other column in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, time

Hi I am new to python switching from R and I have a hard time with this pretty simple task of changing a date based on another column of a pandas data frame. I read several other questions on this and I was hoping that someone could just quickly solve my issue, since I have nobody else to ask but the internet.

I think I have all the ingredients (functions) but I really struggle using pandas df compared to what I am used to in R.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

today=pd.to_datetime(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

d={"Start_Date":[today,today]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
n=len(df)
df["Distance"]=np.round_(np.random.uniform(low=1, high=14, size=n)).astype(int)

df.loc[:,"FutureDate"]=""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["Start_Date"]+pd.DateOffset(row["Distance"]))  
    row["FutureDate"]=row["Start_Date"]+pd.DateOffset(row["Distance"])
```

Why is my FutureDate column empty if the print statement works? 
Is there a more elegant solution than using a loop? I am used to `data.table`where I would use write the function in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code .. it worked for me:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

today=pd.to_datetime(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

d={"Start_Date":[today,today]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
n=len(df)
df["Distance"]=np.round_(np.random.uniform(low=1, high=14, size=n)).astype(int)

df.loc[:,"FutureDate"]=""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["Start_Date"]+pd.DateOffset(row["Distance"]))  
    df.loc[index, "FutureDate"]=row["Start_Date"]+pd.DateOffset(row["Distance"])
```

In fact we need to assign the values on the df itself with the correct index and column.

```
EDIT:
```

A more elegant way:

```
import datetime
# from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

today=pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

d={"Start_Date":[today,today]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
n=len(df)
df["Distance"]=np.round_(np.random.uniform(low=1, high=14, size=n)).astype(int)

df["FutureDate"]=df["Start_Date"] + pd.to_timedelta(df['Distance'],'d')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks, so that was my issue. Maybe someone will have a more "elegant" solution, otherwhise I will mark your answer as correct soon

Comment: Sure, I hope to see a better solution too!

Comment: Glad it helped, Best,